# Disable module output not working on magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2.4, backend, enable-disable, magentomodule, banner

I need to disable module output for the **Magento_Banner** module.

I'm tried to disable the module output using the [DevDocs reference link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html), Also I have followed the same step as per the given reference but it is not working.

I'm using the Magento Commerce Cloud **2.4.3-p1** version.

I followed the same step and tried to run while running below command to check

```
php bin/magento config:show advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Banner
```

After running the command I got the below error
[image]

Note: I also checked with a fresh Magento setup(version **CE 2.4.4**) but did not work.

Comment: Please give the proper module name in the command I showed your image you have given Magento_banner but in actuality you have Magento_Banner.

Comment: the module name is - Magento_Banner.

Comment: I tried to add the code on config.php and ran the upgrade command. It seems it doesn't save the value to the core_config_data table. Did you try to verify if the method works for you? https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0c786907ffe03d0e2990612eec16ee58b00379c5/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Template.php#L96 May be value is picked from config.php and not saved on table.

Comment: After adding to config.php are you able to verify output is disabled or not? Also, the value not saved into table for me too

Answer (score 0):

This will solves your problem ;

You may add following code in the bottom of the app/etc/config.php file. Add the code starting from 'system' => [

```
'Vendor_Module' => 1
    ],
    'system' => [
        'websites' => [
            'base' => [
                'advanced' => [
                    'modules_disable_output' => [
                        'Magento_Banner' => '1'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: I have followed the same as you give but still getting the same error. Also added code in global and website store levels as well

Comment: can you please run setup:upgrade

Comment: please check this link : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html

Comment: Followed same ref and run the all Magento command

Comment: can you please share the latest error you have faced?

Comment: Got the same error as I mentioned in the question,  path dosen't exist. Verify and try again

Comment: can you please share any screenshot or complete error?

Comment: config code-https://i.imgur.com/GdueB4V.png AND checked- https://i.imgur.com/byi1gJb.png, Also run all mage commands

Answer (score 0):

You can check the module status by running this command

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

And You can disable the magento module by running this command

```
php bin/magento module:disable module_name
```

After that you need to run these commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this documentation? I have the same issue as you but solved it reading this: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/disable-magento-banner-output-to-improve-site-performance.html?lang=en